# How to streamline if else for inheriting defaults in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

This code works, but I feel like there is a cleaner way to do this without all of the repetition:

```
def check_out_time                                                                               
  if super                                                                                                
    super                                                                                     
  elsif try(:registration).try(:program).try(:departure_time)                                    
    registration.program.departure_time                                                          
  else                                                                                           
    Settings.default_check_out_time                                                                                           
  end
end
```

This model has an attribute called `check_out_time` and this code basically says "If no check out time is specified, try the departure time of the program for its registration, and if that doesn't exist, use the default setting"

Is there a better way to do write this? Maybe by using the `||` operator?

Comment: || could come in handy but you should really add some abstaction for `try(:registration).try(:program).try(:departure_time) `

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted and no reason to try and cram it into fewer lines, and there's no "repetition" here whatsoever. An if statement with three *completely different branches* is not "repetition".

Comment: For some reason I just don't like all of that `if super super` stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather write:

```
def check_out_time
    super || departure_time || Settings.default_check_out_time
end

def departure_time
    registration.try(:program).try(:departure_time)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're calling super at least once, and possibly twice:

```
if super
  super
```

The remaining can be simplified to:

```
else
  try(:registration).try(:program).try(:departure_time) || Settings.default_check_out_time
end
```

I'm not a fan of more than one .try per expression.  So another way to write this would be to avoid chained try methods:

```
else
  depart_time = registration.program.departure_time rescue nil
  depart_time || Settings.default_check_out_time
end
```

And at this point I would extract that line with the nil out to a separate method call.